# Display managed object in two sections of NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an `NSManagedObject` which has three attributes:

1. Header (`NSString *`)
2. Title (`NSString *`)
3. Favorite (`BOOL`)

I'd like to display the list of these objects using the following scheme:

- Favorites

  - Object 1
  - Object 3
- A Header

  - Object 2
  - Object 3
- B Header

  - Object 1
  - Object 4

Is there any way to do that using `NSFetchedResultsController`? I tried sorting it by `favorite`, `header` to no avail since once object is assigned to favorites section - it won't be displayed in section of its header. Is there any trick that I can use? Should I perform two fetches and reformat the results into one nested array?

Comment: What did you end up doing? I guess trapper below is right.

Comment: I ended up using `NSFetchRequest` with `NSPredicate` as time wasted figuring this one out was far greater than simple implementation of it using instances of aforementioned classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two separate `NSFetchedResultsController's`

Then you need to account for this in each of the various delegate methods.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.mainFetchedResultsController sections] count] + 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return [[[self.favFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
    } else {
        return [[[self.mainFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section - 1] numberOfObjects];
    }
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
    if (section == 0) {
        return @"Favourites";
    } else {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.mainFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section - 1];
        return [sectionInfo name];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Object *object = nil;

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        object = [self.favFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        NSIndexPath *mainIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section -1];
        object = [self.mainFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:mainIndexPath];
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = ...

    ...

    return cell;
}
```